# Error: "Failed to install apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout"

Tags: android, installation, emulation, apk

I have run my application using an emulator. Its taking so long time of about 5 mins to upload & 2 mins of installing my application on my emulator. After the two minutes it fails.

This is the Error console,

```
[2013-03-28 14:13:18 - newwaterreadingapp] ------------------------------
[2013-03-28 14:13:18 - newwaterreadingapp] Android Launch!
[2013-03-28 14:13:18 - newwaterreadingapp] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-28 14:13:18 - newwaterreadingapp] Performing     
com.example.newwaterreadingapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-03-28 14:13:18 - newwaterreadingapp] Automatic Target Mode: using existing     emulator 'emulator-5556' running compatible AVD 'NewAvd_water_electricity_reading'
[2013-03-28 14:13:18 - newwaterreadingapp] Uploading newwaterreadingapp.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2013-03-28 14:18:31 - newwaterreadingapp] Installing newwaterreadingapp.apk...
[2013-03-28 14:20:35 - newwaterreadingapp] Failed to install newwaterreadingapp.apk on   device 'emulator-5556!
[2013-03-28 14:20:35 - newwaterreadingapp] (null)
[2013-03-28 14:20:37 - newwaterreadingapp] Launch canceled!
```

My application is located in `E:\Projects` folder. And I have increased my adb timeout to 15000ms. But still I see that my application is not loaded on to emulator.

Comment: try to clean and build you project and then run it

Comment: I Cleaned my Project and then Tried to run. But still, taking so long time for launching the application..

Comment: does ur emulator works with out any problem.

Comment: Emulator is Showing Home screen Perfectly. But my Application is not loaded. I ran the application multiple times. It shows the above error "Failed to install........"

Comment: I usually have this problem too on windows, when it starts doing this, I close the emulator window and relaunch it from snapshot and it works...it's not a way to solve but at least you can go on working

Comment: restart your ADB. and emulator

Comment: Increase the RAM and Heap size for emulator

Comment: Found solution to my self. My application is of 233 MB size. So It took time for loading on to emulator.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yon can increase your adb timeout setting in eclipse. Go to Preferences-> Android-> DDMS-> find "**ADB connection time out (ms)**"  and give some more higher value.

Also, try to see if your emulator in connected to the DDMS. Either check from DDMS view or run "ADB devices" in command prompt

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `Emulator` then restart.

If you are using `phone` then reboot then phone.

Completely power down and power up. That fixed it for me.

**OR**

In Eclipse, select `Window` → `Preferences`, then `Android` → `DDMS` and set ADB connection time out (ms) to something longer than the default (which is `5000`).

Answer (score 3):

The default timeout of adb is small, so change its value
If using eclipse follow the following path
Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS -> ADB Connection Timeout (ms)

Answer (score 0):

1 reason may be because your emulator is hanged 
shut it down and start a new one
If the new emulator is also taking time to start then just restarts the eclipse 
It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was caused by the emulator not having enough memory. I was running the 3.0 emulator with only 512mb RAM, and it was by pure chance that I saw a tonne of OutOfMemory exceptions in LogCat coming from system processes. Upped it to 1024mb and increased VM heap to 64mb and it installed fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Emulator then open the Emulator and then go to `settings->Apps->Select` and uninstall your Application from Emulator.

Close the Emulator

Now Right click on your `project->Run as->Run Configuration->` in Target Select Automatically pick compatible device option and then click on run.