# Failed to install appname.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, emulation, adt

I keep getting the error, while trying to run my app on an emulator.

```
      Failed to install SalehNotes.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
      Launch canceled!
```

I've been trying almost everything and nothing seems to work..... its extremely frustrating..

anything help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Clean Project, create a new emulator and try again. It happens some times

Comment: i've done this probably about 5 times, still the same result. I've been on this problem for about 4 hours. :(

Comment: Delete and re-import your project. Not even then? Uninstall App from emulator. Try that way.

Comment: Possibly duplicate question, look at this answer

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677640/error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-emulator-5554-timeout/15678091#15678091][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677640/error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-emulator-5554-timeout/15678091#15678091

Answer (score 0):

restart emulator and try to install apk again,this error occurs when emulator not responds or late responds.and do upgrade if you have system with low specifications,also make sure that,emulator size is not too big.

here is the link i found useful for that: [create emulator](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/how-to-create-android-avd-emulator-in-eclipse/)
if you have given more size for sd card then edit emulator and reduce the size of sd card, because more the size of emulator sd card,more the time it will take to launch

Comment: I have one more solution..If this solution also failed then simply delete emulator and create emulator through avd manager

Comment: hey thanks, how do you reinstall the apk, and how do you reduce the size of the emulator? thanks