# WiFi scan app could not upload .. can not tell what is the issue

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-wifi, wifimanager

I have a complete code that scans the near WiFi hot spots and place them in a list but I'm getting the following message in the Console window:

```
[2014-02-21 15:21:40 - WIFI] Failed to install WIFI.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-02-21 15:21:40 - WIFI] (null)
[2014-02-21 15:21:41 - WIFI] Launch canceled!
```

The code dose not have errors (shown below):

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WifiManager mainWifiObj;
    WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
    ListView list;
    String wifis[];

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
        mainWifiObj.startScan();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }

    class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();

            // String bssid = wifiInfo.getBSSID();

            wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
                wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
                Log.i("Data", "ScanResult");

            }
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifis));

        }
    }
}
```

### WIFI Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wifi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
        android:name="com.example.wifi.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="com.example.wifi.ListWifiActivity"
        android:label="This activity has a list of wifi networks" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray" >
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The strings.xml file is shown below too because there was an error which was solves after modifing it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">WIFI</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="title_activity_list_wifi">This activity has a list of wifi networks</string>
</resources>
```

The code is error free but I can not check its functionality without trying it.

Comment: You need to check it on real devices as emulator does not support Wi-Fi and Bluetooth...

Comment: just recreate your emulator and run,it will work..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In terms of running the app:**

[From this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563370/android-simulate-wifi-in-the-emulator) it appears that you can't use the emulator to scan WiFi connections. (thanks to @DimitarDimitrov for his answer on this)

> Currently, while you can use your computer's Internet connection in the emulator, it's not reliable to use it for simulating Wi-Fi. The WifiManager gets confused when you switch/want to test your connectivity state.

More relevant is this:

> While you can use your Internet for simulating HTTP connections and downloading data, finer control over Wi-Fi connectivity should better be done with a device.

I would suggest trying it on a device and proceeding from there.

From a little further reading  [From kmansoft.com on WiFi in the emulator](http://kmansoft.com/2010/07/27/debugging-wifi-in-the-emulator/)

> The emulator has no WiFi support. For your own apps, you can fake it by checking if running in the emulator. For other apps, you’re most likely out of luck.

---

**In terms of the installation** issue on the Emulator here are some links on this error:

Generally ADB timouts and not having sufficient PC power are the causes of the installer error.

[Fail to install apk on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994026/failed-to-install-helloandroid-apk-on-device-emulator-5554)

> In eclipse, you can increase the timeout. In Eclipse, Go to WINDOW-->Prefrences-->android-->DDMS>increase the timeout value. In my case it was 5000 & i incresed it to 10000 & it worked for me .

Also:

> Close the emulator and launch the APP again. That would fix the issue. You might have kept the emulator open for quite some time without doing any activity.

[Time out related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677640/error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-emulator-5554-timeout)

> Yon can increase your adb timeout setting in eclipse. Go to Preferences-> Android-> DDMS-> find "ADB connection time out (ms)" and give some more higher value.
>
> Also, try to see if your emulator in connected to the DDMS. Either check from DDMS view or run "ADB devices" in command prompt

Can you try it throgh ADB directly `adb install -l -r WIFI.apk`

Comment: Yes, but the app should still get installed.

Comment: @FD_ I may have misinterpreted this, I thought this was an error on running the app, rather than installation? Could `WIFI.apk` refer to the fact that 'wifi' is protected or similar?

Comment: No, the logs that the OP posted come from the IDE's console, not from the LogCat. I know these, they appear when installation fails.

Comment: @FD_ that's my mistake, I've updated the answer to include: running the app issues, and actually installing the app issues. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I have increased the adb timeout but I'm still having the same response .... I have an android device to start the application but it is sony ericson Xperia and until now I have failed to uploaed the apk file on it.

Comment: @user3082757 what happens when you try to install it on the device?